# Clarification of the idea of notations used in integral test proof

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

[image]

I'm looking through some notes presented on the Integral test proof and have been confused over the use of the notations and the concepts associated with the use of the notations like
$${x}_{\varepsilon }, \varepsilon ,and\: ,for\: all\: x\geq {x}_{\varepsilon }$$
A simple way to illustrate this I.e., on a number line would be ideal.

Comment: You should first just study the definition of convergence of a function $g(x)\rightarrow I$ as  $x\rightarrow\infty$.  Then apply it to the function $g(x)=\int_a^xf$.

Comment: I am required to understand the use of the notations. Does it changes your judgement if I were to add that I'm currently taking a class in Real analysis?

Comment: No I figured you were taking such a class.

Comment: Is this about sequence and series of functions?